# android mobile website

Tags: codeigniter

how can i hide the url while using android mobile web in android mobile web browser??

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, the only way to do that is to when you display a webpage inside an Android application.

Comment: i try as well you describe. but the url cant hidden. i want to hide that url like as in iphone....

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean cloaking the URL (by using Frames) or hiding the address bar ?

Comment: ya exactly i make thet website onperticular frame but i wats to run that webpage in android mobile... so how can i hide that url???